# Whats a way for me to have code in a script but not ran until asked to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering how in python I'd be able to write code, and not have it executed until a certain input is inputted by the user, for example,

```
a = 1
raw_input("type a if you want to run '1'")
```

but instead of having '1' in this example, it would be code. And not run until the user inputs 'a'

Okay: here is the part of my game I'm working on:

```
balance = 2500
FinalPrice = 0
buy = input("Marijuana plants cost 200$ ea, opium seeds cost 300$")     
while (buy != "o") and (buy != "m"):
    buy = input("That's not on the market! type 'm' if you want to buy Marijuana and 'o' if you want opium!")

if buy =="o":
    o = input("How many opium seeds? Press c to cancel")
    if o =="c":
       input("You cancelled the trade. Type in a command to do something else")
elif buy =="m":
    m = input("How many Marijuana plants? Press c to cancel")
    if m=="0":
        m = input("invalid number, input again")
    elif m =="c":
        input("You cancelled the trade. Type in a command to do something else")
    mprice = (m*200)
    print(mprice)
    FinalPrice-=FinalPrice
    FinalPrice+=mprice
    mbuy = input("This is the final price, press b to buy or c to cancel")
    if mbuy =="c":
        input("You cancelled the trade. Type in a command to do something else")
    elif mbuy =="b":
        if mprice > balance:
            print("Not enough money! Sell more drugs to earn more money.")
        elif mprice < balance:
            print("you bought", m , "Marijuana plants for", mprice , "$")
input("What do you want to do next?"
```

I want to move all of this code to have it when the user types in an input, for example "buy" it executes this code, but only then and I don't want to have to copy + paste it after every input when i ask the user what they want to do next

Comment: *cough* https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler what part in specific?

Comment: Why are you using `raw_input()` on Python 3?

Comment: Because I am very new to python :/

Comment: First, use `input()` instead `raw_input()`. That has been removed on Python 3. Then, maybe you're looking for [`if...else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

Comment: I know what that does, but is there a way to "broadcast"?

Comment: What do you mean about *broadcast* ? And could you add more information about your question? Like add an example program and the  input and output that you wish.

Comment: Then, you want [functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) (other tutorials may be available).

Comment: are you able to make the code I put at the bottom into a callable code?

Comment: As @TessellatingHeckler said, use **function** here will be more clearer and simpler.

Comment: How do I use function in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You want to declare a function.

```
def buy():
    #paste all your code in here
```

Now whenever you want to run the function, all you have to do is call it. You can define lots of other functions the same way and call them too, without copying and pasting any code.

```
command = input("Type buy if you want to buy, and sell if you want to sell.")
if command == 'buy':
    buy()
elif command == 'sell':
    sell()
```

I highly recommend you read the documentation already linked in the comments. It's better programming practice to pass balance and FinalPrice as parameters into the function and return them at the end, and even better practice to define separate variables for each price, but reading the documentation will probably help more than asking here.